# How to override the help messages shown in Django's "set password" step?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I replaced the password set's step HTML with my own HTML, and so far everything's good. Thing is, all tutorials seem to use the `{{form.as p}}` part when the user is changing their password, so the code will be left like this:

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Password recovery{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}

{% if validlink %}

<h1>Password change</h1>
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Change password">
</form>

{% else %}

<h1>Error.</h1>
<p>Please try again.</p>

{% endif %}

{% endblock%}
```

Thing is, when testing it, the page displays this additional help text:

> Your password can’t be too similar to your other personal information.
> Your password must contain at least 8 characters.
> Your password can’t be a commonly used password.
> Your password can’t be entirely numeric.

And I want to modify that text.

I looking for the validator's class in `password_validation.pyi` at `contrib.auth`, and calling it from a **forms.py** I created in my **login** app, changing the `get_help_text` function this way

```
 def get_help_text(self):
       return ngettext(
           "Blah blah, text changed",
           "Blah blah, text changed",
           self.min_length
       ) % {'min_length': self.min_length}
```

But it doesn't seem to be changed in the set password step as expected.

How could I modify these messages (or, better, the whole form displayed on that step)? Thank you beforehand

Comment: How did you change the `get_help_text(...)` method?

Comment: @JPG When I say "change" I meant only to clarify that "return ngettext" part, in which I added the "Blah blah, text changed" string based on an answer on another similar issue I tried on

Comment: The question is ***_how_***? By going to the source and edited?

Comment: @JPG by inheriting the class and adding that string